# nodejs npm package tutorials

Tags: node.js, package, npm

Looking for some tutorials where we have all the information about writing first npm package from scratch, looking forward things like

1. Mandate folder structure if any
2. Initiating package
3. Add dependencies
4. bin folder (why do we need it?)
5. Any AMD dependency

**Moreover how do we convert a common JS api to npm enabled?**

Any pointer or help should be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get things out myself, hence successfully registered the npm package @ https://npmjs.org/package/javascript-boilerplate

Kindly find the answer in the same order as I have asked.

1. There is no mandate for particular folder structure
2. npm adduse and npm publish does the job to register the package
3. Here I was getting the issue, which was essentially driven from jquery 1.8.3 npm package, just removed it and ship the jQuery with my bundle only
4. I didn't need the bin folder
5. I don't think so there is any, it may be needed for global npm install

Answer (score 0):

Here’s how you can create an NPM package for NodeJS. In this example, the purpose of the NPM package will be to create an interface for an existing API.

**Setting up the Project.**

To begin, you need to initialise a NodeJS progress.

Create a new folder for the project, open it with Visual Studio Code (or your preferred editor) and type npm init into the command line. Follow the process onscreen by adding your package’s name and any other details you wish to include. Once this is complete, a package.js file will have been created and you can run npm install axios to install the Axios dependency that we’ll use to make the requests to your API.

**Creating the index.js File.**

Now that your project is set up, we can start writing the code that will interact with your API.

Create a file named index.js and, at the top we'll declare the axios dependency, followed by your API’s base URL. We’ll then create the object that will interface with your API.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const url = 'https://myapi.com';
/**  
 * This object is used to interact with your APIs.  
 * In this example, we'll assume you require a single API key.  
 *  
 * @param {string} apiKey API key.  
 */ 
const MyPackage = function MyPackage(apiKey) {   
  this.apiKey = apiKey; 
}
```

**Adding Your Endpoints.**

To interact with your API, we’ll create functions for each endpoint on your API. These functions will accept all the relevant data, queries and parameters and make the corresponding Axios request, returning the data to the user. See the following example:

```
/**  
 * getDemo  
 *   
 * This `{ func }` method is used to get a demo by ID. 
 * 
 * @param {string} demo_id 
 * 
 * @return {Promise} `{ response }` 
 */ 
MyPackage.prototype.getDemo = async function (demo_id) {   
  const { apiKey } = this;   
  const response = await axios.get(`${url}/demo/${demo_id}`); 
  return response; 
}
```

You can copy this layout for all your endpoints, adding any additional logic you like. It may be advised to catch any errors in the axios request, but this has been omitted above for simplicity. The comment above the function will be shown to the user of your package to explain the purpose of each function, so be sure to include all necessary details.

**Concluding Your Package.**

Once you’ve added all your API’s necessary endpoints, simply add the following code to the index.js file to export the object:

```
module.exports = MyPackage
```

Done! You now have a package that is ready to publish to NPM.

I highly recommend the online tool, [apitopackage.zip](https://apitopackage.zip), which uses AI to generate an NPM package for you (one that is better structured than shown here), instead of creating the package manually.

I hope this helps!